# Xamarin Forms IOS - NSData from a json string

Tags: json, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, nsdata

I'm trying to get an NSData from a json string, to use it later to create an MGLShape (From Mapbox SDK) like this:

```
MGLShape.ShapeWithData(jsonData, 4, out error); //jsonData is the NSData, 4 is the nuint for the type of encoding and ou error is a plain NSError.
```

But i'm not able to serialize the json string into NSData using NSJsonSerialization, the json string is corrected and validated before, (but when i use an NSString from the string, it adds an extra pair of brackets "{ //json }", which i can remove before trying the NSJsonSerialization, here is how i'm trying to achive my goal:

```
string jsonSerialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fc);//Valid Json
NSString json = new NSString(jsonSerialized);//Adds the extra pair of brackets
NSData jsonData = NSJsonSerialization.Serialize(json, NSJsonWritingOptions.SortedKeys, out error);
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: *** +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]: Invalid top-level type in JSON write
```

This error happens with, or without the extra pair of brackets (removed the first and last chars from the NSString), here is a shortned version of my json:
(i used https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ to test the json)

```
{
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "crs":null,
   "features":[
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               -9.000000,
               38.000000
            ]
         },
         "properties":{
            "id":1,
            "icon":"MyIcon.png"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

What am i doing wrong here? how can i parse an json string into an NSData?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found an super easy solution:

```
NSData jsonData = NSData.FromString(jsonSerialized, NSStringEncoding.UTF8);
```